# Mysql regex for numbers

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql database table with rows like this

```
id | values

1 | 5,6,8,1,9

2 | 12,22,5,20

3 | 18,55,3,2
```

I want a help in SELECT statement

To select rows that contain Numbers 1 OR 2

Without selecting rows that contain numbers like 12 or 22

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE values REGEXP '/(^[,])?(1)(^[,])?/';
```

Comment: Use MySQL’s `IN_SET` function.

Comment: I really hope you can convert this into a [properly normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) data structure because comma separated values in a database are rage-inducing.

Comment: `..WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1,values)>0 OR FIND_IN_SET(2,values)>0`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1446005

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you should use: (^|,)[12]($|,)

SELECT * FROM test WHERE values REGEXP '/(^|,)[12]($|,)/';